# VBA Crear listado con valores únicos

Tags: excel, formularios, vba

Tengo una tabla en excel de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Normalmente, si quisiera mostrar información básica de la tabla en un formulario VBA emplearía la siguiente lógica:

```
Me.lista.RowSource = "tabla_repuestos"
Me.lista.ColumnCount = 4
Me.lista.ColumnWidths = "0;209;192;180"
```

Y de esta manera la información se muestra adecuadamente en el formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, mi problemática es que, como pueden ver en la columna A de mi tabla, los 3 registros tienen el mismo ID porque están relacionados, por lo que en realidad solo debería mostrar 1 de estos registros en la lista y no todo, pero no logro entender como puedo hacer para que, al momento de pintar la lista, el sistema solo traiga un único valor.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que la tabla de datos no está normalizada. Es decir, cada registro no es un producto sino una venta/entrega/salida de inventario o algo así, entonces es normal que haya N salidas de un mismo producto. La solución fácil es generar una tabla dinámica que unifique los productos e ignore las cosas como la fecha de entrega y la máquina destinada, etc. Sobre esa podríás generar tu formulario con datos únicos de producto, no?

Comment: Podrías usar un diccionario para llevarte cada ID solo una vez y después rellenar el listbox manualmente. O si tienes Excel365, puedes crear una copia temporal de la tabla pero con registros únicos en otra hoja y cargas desde ahí. PAra eso necesitarías la función [ÚNICOS](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/unique-funci%C3%B3n-unique-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e)

Comment: Para dar contexto, efectivamente la tabla que estas viendo es de salidas, cuando una persona diligencia una salida, por ejemplo 50 latas de Aceite, debe detallar como se distribuyeron esas 50 unidades, ejm: 20 para la Maq 1, 20 para la Maq 2 y 10 para la Maq 3, lo que crea 3 registros en la tabla pero, como se trata de una única salida con un único responsable, los relaciona todos con el mismo id.

Entonces pintar los 3 registros es redundante e impreciso, lo que busco es pintar cada ID distinto una única vez.

Comment: Lo adecuado es que tengas una tabla específicamente para el catalogo de productos y referenciar a esa tabla tu ListBox.

Comment: *lo que busco es pintar cada ID distinto una única vez* Pues con más razón: puedes llevarte a un diccionario cada ID distinto y después de ahí al listbox. Lo que quieras guardar relacionado con cada ID en el diccionario podría ser la suma total de latas de atun(por ejemplo) de ese ID